# Leaked GCP API Keys - Using web service API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, android-security

Google play console pre-launch report says I have leaked GCP API Keys.

I can't restrict a google web service API to the android app. However, I did put it inside a secrets.properties file using gradle secrets plugin.

Is this enough? Is google providing a false error? Or do I need to do more?

Please help (this is my first question)

I tried using the place details android SDK version but it does not allow me to retrieve place details in a specific language whereas the web service version does and retrieving the place details in different languages is important.

Comment: You shouldn't embed your own API keys inside a client app, or they will be extracted.  To keep them safe you need to have your own server act as a proxy for clients.  Clients contact your server, your server passes back the results.  If a client app uses API keys directly it should be the user's own keys.  For some APIs (at least on AWS) you can create temporary users with limited rights and have an app use those using identity based authentication, or for file access you generate temporary access URLs

Answer (score 1):

You can hardcode the Google API key in your application as long as you have API key pinning configured on your key.

The API key pinning protects from the risk of abusing your key by ensuring that only your application can use it.

You can find more details on how to configure API key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restricting-api-keys

You can also find more details on how to secure your API keys here: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices